bannas in pajamas episode
The episode, bananas in pajamas had a wet paint skit in it that was part of a show where kids sang in it. I remember one scene had a girl with black hair, yellow and red overalls but the overalls may have been yellow shorts and red overalls in the end singing with a Hawaiian guy with black hair or white guy with gray hair playing a mini acoustic guitar or full sized or ukulele. Bananas with pajamas was on there dancing live with costumes. They sang you make me wanna shout.

To be absolutely sure since I didn't entirely get your question, you are looking for a specific episode of Bananas in Pajamas, right?

Er, could it possibly be the series 1 episode Wet Paint? ;)

All I know is it probably was a mashup or kids shows into one big video epic show or something like that episode was part of a skit from another show.

I believe this is the episode you are looking for.  Season 1, Episode 15 "Wet Paint".



